# In a shell script how to validate if a given host name belongs to localhostname family

Tags: bash, shell, networking

In a shell script how to validate if a given host name is localhost

for example :-

```
localhost
127.0.0.1
myhostname.com
::1
```

all belong to same machine name, Is there any way to identify that a given host name belongs to localhostname family

Answer (score 1):

Usually all local host names are in /etc/hosts file:

```
grep -c machine_name /etc/hosts
```

if the machine name is among the localhost the command above returns 1 or greater, otherwise is 0.

for example:

```
grep -c myhostname.com /etc/hosts
1

grep -c google.com /etc/hosts
0
```

Not sure if this is exactly you're looking for but I hope it will help.

Beware of partial match, for example if you have 'myhost' in /etc/hosts `grep -c host` will return 1 as well. In this case you'll need to use regular expressions or parse /etc/hosts file with cut, awk and similar tools. Or use the following command:

```
grep -c  '\bmachine name\b'
```

To skip the comments use the command below:

```
grep -v '^#.*' /etc/hosts | grep -c machine_name
```

so full command is

```
grep -v '^#.*' /etc/hosts | grep -c '\bmachine_name\b'
```

Comment: @Ignacio: I've updated the answer, think you mean that issue.

Comment: This will not work, in the scenario Like         #google.com This is commented in /etc/hosts

Comment: I've added a fix for that as well.

Comment: @AlecTMH Still it's a grey area not all host information will be in /etc/hosts file. Thanks very much for the effort you made.

Answer (score 0):

You could check

```
sysctl kernel.hostname
```

i.e

```
sysctl kernel.hostname | grep -c "my_hostname"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to check whether a supplied hostname is the same as localhost:

```
hostname_ip(){
   host "$1" | sed -e 's/.* \([^ ]*[^ .]\)\.*$/\1/'
}

normalize_hostname(){
   local normalized="$1"
   grep -q "^\(\([0-9]{1,3}\)\.\)\{3\}\([0-9]{1,3}\)$" <<< "$normalized" || normalized="$(hostname_ip "$normalized")"
   normalized="$(hostname_ip "$normalized")"
   echo "$normalized"
}

myname="$(normalize_hostname "$(hostname)")"
argname="$(normalize_hostname "$1")"

if [[ "$myname" == "$argname" || "$argname" == "localhost" ]]; then
   ...
```

First, normalize the supplied parameter into format set by **host** utility by running it twice. If IP address is supplied -- checked by regex -- run it only once.

Then compare the value to normalized value of **hostname** utility or to string "localhost".